# propriety: opacity into my background color in css

Tags: html, css

I would like to use the propriety: `opacity` into my background color. However, when I use this propriety, all the elements become transparent. I just want to change the background color.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

```css
body{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

header{
 background-color: #B1DBE8;
 height: 98px;
 opacity: 0.8;
}

.header-block{
 font-size: 11px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding-top: 8px;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #777;
 line-height: 20px;
}

.page-left{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 430px;
}

.page-left-languages{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

.page-right{
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 134px;
}

.page-right-login{
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 margin-right: -100px;
}

nav{
 position: relative;
 top: 6px;
 float: right;
 right: 92px;
}

nav ul{
 list-style: none;
}

nav ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: "Lato","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 27px;
}

nav ul li a{
 padding: 8px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: center;
 border-radius: 3px
}

nav ul li a:hover{
 background-color: #FFF;
 color: black;
}

.active{
 background-color: #cd2122;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 8px 16px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
   <div class="header-block">
    <div class="page-left">Portfolio</div>
    <div class="page-left-languages">Languages</div>
    <div class="page-right">Support</div>
    <div class="page-right-login">Login</div>
   </div>

   <nav>
     <ul>
      <li><a class="active"><href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Plan</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Commission</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
     </ul>

   </nav>
  </header>
 </body>
```

Comment: The reason it does for the elements as well because `header` is parent for `div`

Comment: I am not sure why the question is downvoted and closed, OP has a different question not a transparent background!.

Comment: @Manjuboyz: I don't know why my question is downvoted also... :(

Comment: one way what I see is why don't you use the color code as `background-color` which is needed than relying on opacity, since `header` is the parent for all the elements inside it.

Comment: @Manjuboyz: ahahha it's just, with rgba it's ok for example => `{background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);}` thank you Manjuboyz. :-)

Comment: Great! happy coding :)

Comment: @Manjuboyz: ahaha thank you :-)

Comment: I missed vote from you :P if this is not closed.

Comment: @Manjuboyz: it's closed, sorry... :-(

Comment: No No I got it, I was just kidding.